# How to traverse recursively an HTML tree with Jsoup?

Tags: java, list, recursion, jsoup

I have a html file and I want to traverse the file using first div tag [the image display the html file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KczwZ.png)
my Code is

```
public static void ExtractChild(String content) {

    String data = content;
    ArrayList<String> childList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(data);
    Element div = document.select("div").first();
    Elements divChildren = div.children();
    int size = divChildren.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data = divChildren.get(i).toString();
            
            System.out.println(data);
            ExtractChild(data);
        }
    } else {
        childList.add(data);

    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        
    }

}
}
```

I am getting an Html file as String First I catch First div tag and get all its all children. In my image the parent has 3 child and first child has 2 child.
i am adding the child if it does not have any sub child( else portion) the problem occurs in If portion when it founds the sub child it reset the value of i and the it is not able to backtrack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the [NodeTraversor](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/NodeTraversor.html) and it companion class [NodeVisitor](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/NodeVisitor.html) from the Jsoup API.

**NodeTraversor** traverses recursively an node tree. Each time it hits the start tag or the end tag (if exists) of a node, it calls a given **NodeVisitor**.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String html = "<div id=\"d1\">" + //
            "<div id=\"d1.0\">" + //
            "<div id=\"d1.0.0\">" + //
            "1.0.0" + //
            "</div>" + //
            "<div id=\"d1.0.1\">" + //
            "1.0.1" + //
            "</div>" + //
            "</div>" + //
            "<div id=\"d1.1\">" + //
            "1.1" + //
            "</div>" + //
            "<div id=\"d1.3\">" + //
            "1.3" + //
            "</div>" + //
            "</div>";

    List<String> childList = new ArrayList<>();
    NodeVisitor myNodeVisitor = new MyNodeVisitor(childList);
    NodeTraversor traversor = new NodeTraversor(myNodeVisitor);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Element firstDiv = doc.select("div:first-of-type").first();
    if (firstDiv == null) {
        System.err.println("Unable to find any div.");
    } else {
        traversor.traverse(firstDiv);

        for (String child : childList) {
            System.out.println(child);
        }
    }
}

private static class MyNodeVisitor implements NodeVisitor {

    private List<String> childList;

    public MyNodeVisitor(List<String> childList) {
        if (childList == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("childList cannot be null.");
        }

        this.childList = childList;
    }

    @Override
    public void head(Node node, int depth) {
        if (node.childNodeSize() == 0) {
            childList.add(node.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void tail(Node node, int depth) {

    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1.0.0

1.0.1

1.1

1.3
```